# How to truncate specific part of string if present

Tags: r, string, character

Let's consider vector following:

```
x <- c("GDP_UK", "GDP_US", "GDP_UK_diff2_L2", 
       "INC","GDP_UK_L2", "GDP_US_level", "INC_UK", "INC_L1", "INC_diff1")
```

As you can see there is a vector containing some strings.

What I want to do is to find those who have `"_diff(number)", "_L(number), _level` within it and truncate this part of the string.

What I want to end up with is a vector following:

`c("GDP_UK", "GDP_US", "GDP_UK", "INC", "GDUP_UK", "GDP_US", "INC_UK", "INC", "INC")`

As you can see all `_diff, _L, _level`  were truncated to obtain raw strings.

And I'm not sure how to do it. I tried code

`x[grepl(paste(c("diff", "level", "_L"), collapse = "|"), x)]`

to obtain only elements which include `grepl` or `level` or `_L`, but I haven't any idea how to cut it. Tried something with `substring` but wasn't sure exactly how to specify up to which letter it should be deleted. Do you have any idea how it can be done ?

** EDIT **

WE can use code following:

```
x <- gsub(pattern = "_L", replacement = "", x)
x <- gsub(pattern = "_diff", replacement = "", x)
x <- gsub(pattern = "_level", replacement = "", x)
```

However we will end up with remaining numbers at the end of the strings:

```
 "GDP_UK"   "GDP_US"   "GDP_UK22" "INC"      "GDP_UK2"  "GDP_US"   "INC_UK"   "INC2"     "INC1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the regex `"_L\\d*"`, etc. This matches an underscore, L and zero or more digits.

In full

```r
x <- c("GDP_UK", "GDP_US", "GDP_UK_diff2_L2", 
       "INC","GDP_UK_L2", "GDP_US_level", "INC_UK", "INC_L1", "INC_diff1")

gsub("_L\\d*", "", x)
gsub("_diff\\d*", "", x)
gsub("_level\\d*", "", x)


# or in one go:
library(stringr)
x %>% 
  str_replace_all("_L\\d*", "") %>% 
  str_replace_all("_diff\\d*", "") %>% 
  str_replace_all("_level\\d*", "")
#> [1] "GDP_UK" "GDP_US" "GDP_UK" "INC"    "GDP_UK" "GDP_US" "INC_UK" "INC"   
#> [9] "INC"

## or even in one go:
gsub("_(L|diff|level)\\d*", "", x)
#> [1] "GDP_UK" "GDP_US" "GDP_UK" "INC"    "GDP_UK" "GDP_US" "INC_UK" "INC"   
#> [9] "INC"
```